# Поиск словарей в списке по подстрокам ключей из другого списка

Tags: python

Итак, на минуточку представим, что у нас есть два списка:

`AI = [{"Паша Техник": 1}, {"Паша Техник жив": 2}]`

`in1 = ["Паша", "Техник"]`

с помощью цикла for нужно попробовать найти каждый элемент из списка in1 в списке AI

Я пытался сделать это через метод index(), и найти уже индекс элемента и работать с ним, но Питон вежливо сказал мне "Нет, парень, так не пойдет! Либо ты нормально работаешь со мной, либо я поднимаю эту ошибку ребром!"

Например, надо найти слово "Паша" в AI

В итоге, у меня ничего не вышло, может у вас есть идеи?

```
import re

ai = [{"Паша Техник": "1"}, {"Паша Техник жив": "2"}]
in1 = []
#print(ai.index("как ты?"))
while True:
    key = input(" >> ") # разделение сообщения на части списка
    key = key.split(" ")
    for z in key: # Работа с индексом, тут и была ошибка
        in1.append(ai.index(z))
        print(int1)
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ai.py", line 15, in <module> in1.append(ai.index(z))
ValueError: 'Паша' is not in list
```

Comment: Покажите ваш код и полный текст ошибки.

Comment: `import re

ai = [{"Паша Техник": "1"}, {"Паша Техник жив": "2"}]
in1 = []

#print(ai.index("как ты?"))
while True:
 key = input(" >> ")

 # разделение сообщения на части списка
 key = key.split(" ")
 for z in key:

  # Работа с индексом, тут и была ошибка 
  in1.append(ai.index(z))
 print(int1)`

Comment: root@Ar4ikov:/AI# python3.5 ai.py
 >> Паша Техник
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ai.py", line 15, in <module>
    in1.append(ai.index(z))
ValueError: 'Паша' is not in list
root@Ar4ikov:/AI#

Comment: Прикрепите пример входных/выходных данных

Comment: Input >> Паша Техник

Output >> 1

Input >> Паша Техник жив

Output >> 2

Comment: @Ar4ikov, на будущее: если вас просят показать код (или текст ошибки, или еще что-то), то подразумевается, что нужно отредактировать вопрос, и добавить в него код.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [49]: def foo(word):
    ...:     for i in AI:
    ...:         if word in i:
    ...:             return i[word]
    ...:

In [50]: foo('Паша Техник')
Out[50]: 1

In [51]: foo('Паша Техник жив')
Out[51]: 2
```